# Artinian and Noetherian ring of matrices

Tags: matrices, noetherian, artinian

I am trying to solve an exercise about Artinian an Noetherian rings of $2 \times 2$ matrices but I really can't get to a solution. The exercise is the following:
Set
$$
R = \left\{
    \begin{pmatrix}
    q & 0 \\
    r & s \\
    \end{pmatrix} \mid q \in \mathbb{Q}, \ r,s \in \mathbb{R}
\right\}.
$$
Show that $R$ is left artinian and left noetherian, but it is neither right artinian nor right noetherian.

I think I managed to prove it is left noetherian (showing that every left ideal is finitely generated), but I can't find a way to prove it is artinian since (I guess) it is necessary to show explicitly that every descending chain of left submodules is stationary.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a $\Bbb Q$-vector subspace of $\Bbb R$. Then the set
of $$\pmatrix{0&0\\v&0}$$
with $v\in V$ is a right ideal of $R$. As $\Bbb R$ is an infinite-dimensional $\Bbb Q$-vector space, it is easy to prove that it has non-trivial ascending and
descending sequences of $\Bbb Q$-vector subspaces.