# Left- and right artinian

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, artinian

Let $R$ be the ring defined by
$$R=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\mid a\in\mathbb{Q},c,d\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$ I want to show that it is left-artinian. I have calculated all possible left ideals:
$$L_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} $$
$$L_2=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Q}&0\\\mathbb{R}&\mathbb{R}\end{pmatrix}$$
$$L_3=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\\mathbb{R}&0\end{pmatrix} $$
$$L_4=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&\mathbb{R}\end{pmatrix} $$
$$L_5=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Q}&0\\\mathbb{R}&0\end{pmatrix} $$
$$L_6=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\\mathbb{R}&\mathbb{R}\end{pmatrix} $$
$$L_7=\mathbb{R}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&r\end{pmatrix} $$for $r \in\mathbb{R}.$ How can I conclude that $R$ is left artinian?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947263/techniques-for-proving-a-ring-is-artinian). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593456/artinian-and-noetherian-ring-of-matrices), for the continuation of this exercise.

Comment: @DietrichBurde could I use the following: $I_v:=\mathbb{Q}\pmatrix{0&0\\v&0}$ for $v\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $I_0, I_{\pi}, I_{\pi^2}, ...$ is doing the job?

Comment: In the future, you ought to accumulate your work on a problem in a single post, not [delete and repost the problem as you get feedback](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4564316/29335). This will be construed as dodging moderation (and kind of wasting everyone's time, too.)